# Template/Cover page

Tags: templates

I'm searching for the template of [this document](http://www.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.278918.1460619857!/menu/standard/file/science-writing-latex.pdf):

[image]

How can one create such a cover page?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,eso-pic,contour}
\contourlength{.4pt}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\TITLE}{%
\sffamily
{\Large Stockholms universitet | Institutionen f\"or naturgeografi\\[80mm]}
{\Huge\bfseries\color{orange}\contour{orange}{Scientific writing with \LaTeX}\\[50mm]}
{\huge\bfseries Peter Jansson}
}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node (A) at (current page.south west) {};
\node (B) at ([xshift=40mm] current page.north west) {};
\node (C) at ([xshift=40mm,yshift=-50mm] current page.north west) {};
\fill[blue!50!black] (A) rectangle (B);
\node[anchor=north west,outer sep=5mm,inner sep=0pt] at (C) {\parbox{15cm}{\TITLE}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\hbox{}\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image]